# how to compare time in human format in lua?

Tags: lua

Is there a way to convert human readable time "09:41:43" to some comparable format?

What I want is `function timeGreater(time1, time2)`, satisfied the below assertion

```
assert(true == timeGreater("09:41:43", "09:00:42"))
assert(false == timeGreater("12:55:43", "19:00:43")))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like a simple string comparison may be sufficient (assuming time is valid):

```
function timeGreater(a, b) return a > b end

assert(true == timeGreater("09:41:43", "09:00:42"))
assert(false == timeGreater("12:55:43", "19:00:43"))
```

Comment: No, string comparison return nil.

Comment: Sorry, I found it works as in a file, but not in lua command prompt. ;)

Comment: @NeilJiang, it should work both in a file and in interactive mode.

Comment: @Cubic, no, `assert(42)` succeeds, `assert(true==42)` fails.

Answer (score 4):

Converting your time to seconds should work. The code below might work, LUA isn't my strong suit!

```
function stime(s)
    local pattern = "(%d+):(%d+):(%d+)"
    local hours, minutes, seconds = string.match(s, pattern)
    return (hours*3600)+(minutes*60)+seconds
end

function timeGreater(a, b)
    return stime(a) > stime(b)
end
```